# check box with accept terms

Tags: php, html, checkbox

I would like to check whether user checked box or not with php code. how can I do this?? and if checked then what kind of value I will get??

```
<input name="accept" type="checkbox" class="tickbox" value="" />
```

Comment: You should set a `value`, it makes things much easier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this specific case, you will get `$_POST['accept'] == ''` , which is immensely un-useful.

You'll want to add a value to that tag:

```
<input name="accept" type="checkbox" class="tickbox" value="1" />
```

With that value, you'll get `$_POST['accept'] == '1'` when the checkbox is checked, and no `'accept'` key at all when the checkbox is not checked.

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="hidden" name="accept" value="0" />
<input type="checkbox" name="accept" value="1" />
```

if unchecked : return hidden field’s value => 0

if checked : return checkbox’s value => 1

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a value assigned to the checkbox. If the check box is ticked, this value will be returned when the form is submitted. The other option is to use a Javascript to check this before submission.